# what are the special tithis for different deities?

Tags: gods, goddess, tithi

Chaturthi is considered special for Ganesa "Sankata hara chaturthi".  What is the special tithi for other prominent deities and are there legends associated with them?

Answer (score 3):

This list is derived from the *Agnipurāṇa*, *Kālikapurāṇa* & the 2 *Pañcarātra* texts *Sanatkumārasaṁhita* & *Pādma saṁhitā*

*Amāvasyā* - *pitṛ*s

*Pratipadā* - *Brahmā*, *Kuvera*, *Agni*

*Dvitīyā* - *Aśvinīkumāra*s, *Lakṣmī*, *Brahmā*

*Tṛtīyā* - *Pārvatī*, *Kuvera*

*Caturthī* - *Gaṇeśa*

*Pañcamī* - *Lakṣmī*, *Candra*, *nāga*s

*Ṣaṣṭhī* - *Kārtikeya*

*Saptamī* - *Sūrya*

*Aṣṭamī* - *Śiva*, *Ādyāśakti*

*Navamī* - *Ādyāśakti*

*Daśamī* - *Yama*, *nāga*s

*Ekādaśī* - *Viṣṇu*, *ṛṣi*s, *Indra*

*Dvādaśī* - *Viṣṇu*

*Trayodaśī* - *Kāmadeva*

*Caturdaśī* - *Śiva*, *Aśvinīkumāra*s

*Pūrṇimā* - *Brahmā*, *Candra*, other *dikpāla*s

Answer (score 2):

A list regarding the origin of some deities and on which specific Tithis they are to be worshipped is found in Varaha Purana.

Quoting from the book "Essence of Varaha Purana":

[**Pratpada Tithi -- Agni**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=8)

> Brahma confirmed Pratipada as a day of significance for Agni. Brahma
> blessed Agni that Pratipada be popularised among all the Lokas and
> worship to Agni by way of fasting (Upavas) or at the most by taking
> milk would quality a devotee to acquire prosperity and Tejas
> (radiance) during the current birth and to secure Kingship in the next
> birth and certainly please the Pitru Loka.

[**Dwitiya -- Aswini Kumaras**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=9)

> Aswini Kumars had ‘Darshan’of Narayana and were blessed with boons of
> securing portions of Yajna, the authority of obtaining Amrit along
> with Devas, handsome figures, radiance and knowledge of medicine. As
> the Aswini Kumars are two in number, Brahma designated the second day
> of month or ‘Dviteeya’as the day of worship to them. Whoever reads or
> hears the story of Asvini Kumars and recites Narayana Matra would be
> blessed with noble sons and be relieved of sins.

[**Tritiya -- Parvati/Gauri**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=10)

> Devas and indeed the whole world misfired and Siva opened His third
> eye to punish Manmadha by converting him as Ashes! As time passed,
> Lord Siva married Devi Parvati and was blessed with Son, Lord
> Subrahmanya who annihilated Takasura the dreaded Demon. Since the
> birth and wedding of Devi Gauri as also of Devi Parvati coincided on
> the Thriteeya day of a month, Lord Brahma declared that this day is
> worthy of special worship and austerity to Devi Gauri / Devi Parvati.
> Both men and women ought to avoid consumption of salt or salted
> material and those who observe this practice would certainly become
> prosperous, healthy and famous.

[**Chaturthi -- Ganesha**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=11)

> Since Ganapati was born on Chaturthi, this day of each month is
> worthy of His worship; but Bhadrapada Sukla Paksha Chaturdhi is the
> most auspicious day for a fulfledged worship with ‘Shodasa Upacharas’
> or Sixteen Services of Avahana ( Welcome), Asana ( Seating), Padyam (
> water for washing feet), Arghya (water for sipping), Snana or body
> wash, Gandham (Sandal wood paste), Dhupam (Incense), Deepam ( offering
> lights), Naivedyam ( Food and Fruits) Tambula ( betel leaves and
> nuts), Paneeya (coconut water), Vastram (clothing), Alankaram (
> Decoration), Abharanam (Jewellery), Stotram (Extolling) and ‘Arati’
> (Camphor lighting).

[****Panchami -- Nagas****](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=12)

> Unfortunately, even the well meaning serpents of non-poisonous type
> are hunted out and killed by human beings. But those remaining type
> are venerated especially girls desirous of marrying good husbands and
> women craving for children by providing milk and eats. Come Naga
> Panchami, especially in the week following Deepavali celebrations,
> women observe fast and refrain from eating sour and milk praparations
> of food in several parts of Bharat till date.

**[Shashti -- Karthikeya](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=13)**

> The birth of Kartikeya at the Krittika Star on the Sixth day of the
> bright fortnight of Margasira month (Krittika Nakshatra of Shashthi
> Tithi of Suddha Paksha of Margasirsha Month) brought relief to the
> Universe, immense joy to the Siva Couple, sense of liberation to all
> Devas who were indeed the direct beneficiaries since Brahma’s boon was
> that only Siva’s son could terminate the Demon Tarakasura and finally
> great fear and apprehension to Tarakasura and followers! Brahma had
> formally declared Shashthi of every month would be a day of austerity
> and fast only with ‘Phalaahar’ or fruits as food. Those who are deviod
> of sons, prosperity and status ought to observe the fast and recite
> the above Karikeya Stuti for instant results

[**Saptami -- Surya**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=14)

> He is the known Deity from the beginning, one calls Him Aditya.
> Although the presence of Surya was a matter of immense happiness
> initially, Devas started to feel the excessive illumination and heat
> and as such prayed to Him to tone down these to bearable levels;They
> said that He was too sizzling and literally burning Devalokas; the
> glow emerging from the Chariot is too dazzling to look at; that He was
> always invited to share the oblations of Ghee ( Classified butter) in
> Yagnas and they were grateful to do so; but He must become far less
> blistering and radiant to limits of tolerance and that they would
> sincerely beseech Him to do so. Sun God responded to the requests of
> Devas and since that day of ‘Saptami’ became visible at Prithvi also
> initially.Those human beings on Earth sincerely worship Surya Deva
> along with recitation of ‘Aditya Hridayam’ on this day would certainly
> have their desires fulfilled.

[**Ashtami -- Ashta Matrikas**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=15)

> The combined strength of Marikas is an extraordinary might of Eight
> Shaktis providing security and propitiousness to devotees and Lord
> Brahma declared ‘Ashtami Thithi’ in the Monthly Calendar. Those who
> observe this particular day with fast by eating ‘Bel patra’ with
> devotion are blessed with excellent health, well being and
> contentment.

[**Navami -- Durga**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=16)

> The Navami of each month should be celebrated with sincere dedication
> to Devi Durga by consuming only prasad made of wheat flour after
> observing day long fast till the evening and by reciting Durga Sukti
> as given above. For sure, men and women who keep this as a regular
> practice on Navami days would attract Devi Durga’s kind blessings.

[**Dashami -- Ten directions**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=17)

> He also selected Dashami to observe the day for penance and eat only
> ‘Dahi’ or curd to protect human beings from movement of Grahas,
> changes of ‘Ayanas’or Solar Progress and transformations of ‘Ritus’ or
> Seasons and astrological and astronomical aberrations.

[**Ekadashi -- Kubera**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=18)

> Also, worship of Kubera on Ekadashi day by cooking eats with the help
> of clean Agni- preferably by the person who eats himself after
> day-long fast would instantly make him eligible for wealth and also
> protection of wealth so earned.

[**Dwadashi -- Vishnu**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=19)

> Thus Supreme Narayana strengthened Lord Vishnu physically, mentally
> and spiritually as the Personification of Himself to assume the tasks
> ahead. He also made an arrangement that from then on, Vishnu’s worship
> all over the Three Worlds would be observed on Dwadasis during every
> month and those human beings-be they men or women- who keep fast till
> the dusk while reciting ‘Vishnu Stotras’and eat ‘Ghrita-pura Bhojan’
> or meals with Ghee (Classified butter) are destined to reach Heavens
> after death and enjoy peaceful and contented life therebefore! Those
> who read or hear about Vaishnavi Srishti or Vishnu’s Glories should
> qualify themselves for better times ahead.

[**Trayodashi -- Dharma**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=20)

> Lord Brahma who flew down to Swarga Loka from Satya loka by his Swan
> chariot, complimented Dharma Purush and commended that from then
> onward human beings should observe ‘Trayodasi’ Day, perform Shraddh
> and offer ‘Ksheer’ (Sweet Milk and cooked Rice) to fore fathers to
> ensure that their past sins are demolished and longevity and
> well-being assured.

[**Chaturdashi -- Rudra**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=21)

> Thereafter Brahma declared that worship of Rudra Deva on the
> ‘Chaturdasi Day’ of a month by sincere devotion and austerity would be
> blessed.

[**Amavasya -- Pitrus**](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/varaha/bookview.php?chapnum=22)

> Moreso, He designated ‘Amavasya’ as the most important day for worship
> to ‘Pitras’ and Tanmatras as well. Human beings perform Tarpanas along
> with ‘Kusha’ and ‘Tilas’on Amavasyas falling in each month which would
> indeed provide contenment to Pitras as well as Tanmatras. Thus
> Amavasya is required to be the special day when fast is observed and
> ‘tildaan’ is performed without fail, and that would not only give
> satifaction to Pitras but the Kartas or the Performing Devotees who
> are provided ‘Iham’or during the current birth of prosperity, peace,
> health and longevity but also ‘Param’ or post life.